# Can't Save files in Libre Office Writer

Tags: firefox, icons, libreoffice

I successfully upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 yesterday without any issues. (Probably just dumb luck)
So far, all seems OK. I'm now using Libre Office 7.4 (or whichever version comes with 22.04). There are a few changes that I've noticed & like over the older 20.04 version. Of course, there are a **FEW** exceptions...

The most significant of which is my inability to save my recipes to the proper folder. I 'm pretty sure it's just my inability to double click fast enough to open the folder I'm wanting. I had a similar problem with 20.04, but always managed to open the appropriate folders. Now though, in 22.04, I cannot open the appropriate folder no matter how fast I double click. (Apparently, not fast enough)

I tried to adjust the double click speed in "Mouse Settings", but that setting isn't there or I missed it somehow...

What can I do to fix this? (I'll need step-by-step instructions as I'm not all well-versed in Ubuntu, just in Windows) (I hardly ever use the command line, I mostly use the GUI)

I could also use help in explaining the change in 22.04 concerning FireFox. I read that now FF is a different kind of app. BUT, if I press the super key & search for "FireF", FireFox is displayed, I can just click it to run it.

In 20.04, I had an icon for FireFox in my taskbar. In 22.04 though this icon is no longer there even though all my other icons are.

Is there a way to add a FireFox icon in the taskbar? I manged to set FireFox as my default browser, but that didn't fix anything that I could tell..

Comment: For FF, click on the app list (lower right corner), find FF, the R click and select "Add to Favorites".

Comment: One way to solve the double-click problem is to switch to single cklick. There is usually an option in the file manager settings. As for Firefox, it is the same "app", packeged differently (dev vs snap), and mostly works the same.

Comment: The supplied snap version of FF will only download files into the Downloads folder, even if you want them elsewhere -- a safety feature I guess, but really not something I like.

Comment: I do not like that "feature" in FF either, yukko ...

Comment: I do not like that "feature" in FF either, yukko ... Thanx for the clarification on snap vs. dev   ...   I changed the double clicking to single clicking in 20.04...   If I use "files", I can navigate to anywhere since "files" uses single clicking to navigate, but not the save function in Libre Office Writer,  Is this a L.O.W. problem???

Answer (score 0):

FireFox comes as a snap app on Ubuntu 22.04. That doesn't mean its a different firefox as you describe it. That means that apt will not longer manage your firefox installation, but rather snap will.

To pin it to the bar, right click on the icon when its running and click add to favorites.